Adding Dynamic Shape to Map Series Layout in ArcGIS Pro
I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.4.0.
I have mapped a number of survey points within a given property boundary, and I have formatted a layout with 2 map frames:

One that is an overview map of the entire property,
and a second map frame that is a close-up of an individual point.

I have created a map series that has given me an output for each point, where the second map frame is focused on a different point in each, with dynamic text that adjusts to give data on the point visible in each output.
However, I would like to add a simple shape (a circle) to the overview map frame to basically indicate which point (in the context of the larger map) is being highlighted in the second, more zoomed-in, map frame.
The 'map series' tool has been helpful in automatically generating all of these maps for me, but I find that I am unable to add this indicator circle because I am unable to adjust its location individually for each output layout. If I set it to circle one point on the overview map, it will be circling the same point in all of the outputs rather than being able to adjust it to circle whichever point is relevant for that particular layout.
Is there any way to add a 'dynamic shape', similar to dynamic text? Or just to adjust the settings to make the shape a different location for each output of the map series?

A screenshot would help people understand your question.

I was able to solve this by using the 'extent indicator' feature, and using the 'collapse to point' feature within the extent indicator properties, setting the point symbology to a large circle with no fill and an outline of my desired color/line thickness
